# How to run Android UI tests properly on CircleCI 2.0?

Tags: android, circleci

Trying to upgrade my Android project to **CircleCI 2.0**.  Everything is fine, but having trouble of running Android UI tests with emulator.

- Log says `com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: No connected devices!`
- I've actually downloaded an emulator image and set it up (coz CircleCI's default Android Docker image doesn't come with emulator): `sdkmanager "system-images;android-22;default;armeabi-v7a" && echo "no" | avdmanager create avd -n test -k "system-images;android-22;default;armeabi-v7a" && (emulator64-arm -avd test -noaudio -no-boot-anim -no-window -accel on) &`
- `adb devices` returns no device :(

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Example `circle.yml`:

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/android:api-26-alpha
    steps:
      - run:
          name: Setup emulator
          command: sdkmanager "system-images;android-22;default;armeabi-v7a" && echo "no" | avdmanager create avd -n test -k "system-images;android-22;default;armeabi-v7a"
      - run:
          name: Launch emulator
          command: export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${ANDROID_HOME}/emulator/lib64:${ANDROID_HOME}/emulator/lib64/qt/lib && emulator64-arm -avd test -noaudio -no-boot-anim -no-window -accel on
          background: true
      - run:
          name: Run Tests
          command: ./gradlew :demo:connectedAndroidTest
```

**Note**:

- Some certain architecture image is not provided by Google, e.g. API level 26 doesn't have ARM EABI v7a System Image, that's why I choose `system-images;android-22;default;armeabi-v7a` above.  To see which images are available, run command `sdkmanager --list --verbose | grep system-images`.
- You need to set an environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` with `lib64` and `qt` path, otherwise you'll probably encounter `ERROR: Could not load OpenGLES emulation library [lib64OpenglRender]` or `error while loading shared libraries: libQt5Widgets.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
  Exited with code 127`.  This is due to [a bug from Android SDK](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37137213).
- To run a command in the background on CircleCI, it's not like the usual way just append `&` to the end of command, that will be killed by the hangup (HUP) signal eventually.  The correct way is to say `background: true`.

Comment: I copy and paste your script by adding steps but it crashes on the launch of the emulator. I get this error: `emulator: ERROR: Could not load OpenGLES emulation library [lib64OpenglRender]: lib64OpenglRender.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
emulator: ERROR: Could not load OpenGLES emulation library [lib64OpenglRender]: lib64OpenglRender.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
emulator: ERROR: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, use '-gpu off' to disable it.`

Comment: @filol thanks for the feedback.  I just revised my answer, the change is at the env variable part `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.  Could you please try again and let me know?  BTW, just to confirm, are you using ARM emulator?

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply but when I apply your patch, which corrects the problem of the emulator, gradle crash: `Gradle build daemon disappeared unexpectedly (it may have been killed or may have crashed)`. I suppose it is related to a problem of memory, I will investigate. Yes i'm using ARM emulator.

Comment: My pleasure.  Yes, that fixed the emulator problem.  And your memory problem will be fixed by adding `_JAVA_OPTIONS: "-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap"`.  For more details, you can check my article here: https://medium.com/@thyrlian/migrating-circleci-1-2-for-android-77a63219d64c

Comment: Very good article but I still have a memory error after putting _JAVA_OPTIONS

Comment: Then you need to try to tweak it, for example: add this `-Xms1024m -Xmx1536m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=1536m` also to _JAVA_OPTIONS.

Comment: I thought it was not possible as the following link sugests: https://support.circleci.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000028928-Testing-with-Android-emulator-on-CircleCI-2-0

Comment: @DaniloDeQueiroz it's actually not true, please check here, it's running UI test: https://github.com/thyrlian/AwesomeValidation/blob/master/circle.yml#L32

Comment: @JingLi it looks like a jerry-rig job for me, the memory limitations on circleCI makes unfeasible to run on the same machine where the build runs with a good performance and reliability, I run only the junit tests on circleci and the ui tests I give the job for firebase testlab.

Comment: @DaniloDeQueiroz it's not a jerry-rig job, it's a serious solution provided by CircleCI.  Regarding the memory limitation, you can choose what you need (they ask you to pay, for example higher RAM, I totally understand, coz they need to be profitable, it's mentioned here: https://circleci.com/product/).  Of course you're free to select Firebase.

Comment: @JingLi I'm testing your approach, just one question: Is There a way to use x86 emulator or x86-64 emulator instead of armv7.

Comment: @DaniloDeQueiroz it depends on how CircleCI run their docker environment.  ARM emulator is host machine independent, can run anywhere - Linux, macOS, VM and etc. While the performance is a bit poor. On the contrary, x86 emulator requires KVM, which means only runnable on Linux.  If you wanna know more, please check here: https://github.com/thyrlian/AndroidSDK#emulator

Comment: Guys, I have emulator64-arm command not found, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 4):

Following is an example `config.yml` with which i managed to get my Android espresso tests working some time back using circle ci. May be useful for someone.

Location of the `config.yml`: create `.circleci` directory at root of the project and keep `config.yml` inside that.

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    working_directory: ~/code
    docker:
      - image: circleci/android:api-28-alpha
    environment:
      JVM_OPTS: -Xmx3200m
    steps:
      - checkout
      - restore_cache:
          key: jars-{{ checksum "build.gradle" }}-{{ checksum  "app/build.gradle" }}
      - run:
         name: Chmod permissions
         command: sudo chmod +x ./gradlew
      - run:
          name: Download Dependencies
          command: ./gradlew androidDependencies
      - save_cache:
          paths:
            - ~/.gradle
          key: jars-{{ checksum "build.gradle" }}-{{ checksum  "app/build.gradle" }}
      - run:
          name: Lists installed targets
          command: android list target
          environment:
          TERM: dumb
      - run:
          name: Show list of system-images
          command: sdkmanager --list --verbose | grep system-images
      - run:
          name: Setup Emulator
          command: sdkmanager "system-images;android-21;default;armeabi-v7a" && echo "no" | avdmanager create avd -n test -k "system-images;android-21;default;armeabi-v7a"
      - run:
          name: Launch Emulator
          command: |
                  cd ${ANDROID_HOME}/emulator;ls
                  export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${ANDROID_HOME}/emulator/lib64:${ANDROID_HOME}/emulator/lib64/qt/lib
                  emulator -avd test -no-window -noaudio -no-boot-anim -no-window -accel on
          background: true
      - run:
          name: Wait emulator
          command: |
              circle-android wait-for-boot
              adb shell input keyevent 82
      - run:
          name: Run Espresso UI Tests
          command: ./gradlew :app:connectedDebugAndroidTest
      - store_artifacts:
          path: app/build/reports
          destination: reports
      - store_test_results:
          path: app/build/test-results
```